# How do I only select files that are in a txt list in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I get $selected_files to populate with files that are included in $fileList.  $fileList is a text file that only contains the name of the file, path and extension not included.  I have tried the following:

```
$fileList = "C:\Users\HKJ\Desktop\Test\ListofFilesToDelete.txt"
$selected_files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder\*" -File -Name -Include @(Get-Content $fileList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```bsh
$fileList = "C:\Users\HKJ\Desktop\Test\ListofFilesToDelete.txt"
$fileBaseNames = Get-Content $fileList
$selected_files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder\*" -File -Name | Where-Object BaseName -in $fileBaseNames
```

Using the built in `-Include` on `Get-ChildItem` only works for simple things. Here we use the `BaseName` property on the files and use the `-in` operator to see whether the array `$fileBaseNames` contains that name. The `BaseName` property contains just the file name without the extension.

If you are on an older version of Powershell you might need to change the last line to this:

```bsh
$selected_files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder\*" -File -Name | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -in $fileBaseNames }
```

Comment: 1st solution worked but I had to remove the -Name:

$fileList = "C:\Users\HKJ\Desktop\Test\ListofFilesToDelete.txt"
$fileBaseNames = Get-Content $fileList
$selected_files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder\*" -File  | Where-Object BaseName -in $fileBaseNames

Comment: Yes, if you want the actual objects you need to remove that. But you had included it in the question, so I assumed that's what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$filelist = Get-Content "C:\Users\HKJ\Desktop\Test\ListofFilesToDelete.txt"
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$filelist.Contains([io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name))}
```